# How to delete duplicate photos from Google Photos, some stored on Google Drive AND Google Photos and some are ONLY on Google Photos

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I recently un-synced and then re-synced a folder containing lots of photos using Google back-up and sync. Un-syncing the folder removed all the photos from Google Drive but not from Google Photos so when I re-synced the folder my photos were uploaded to Google photos again as duplicates.

I would like to automatically delete the duplicates from Google Photos and don't want to do it manually as there are thousands of them. One copy of each photo is not stored on Google Drive and is only stored on Google Photos, meaning [this method](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/109695/how-can-i-remove-duplicates-in-google-photos) did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.